# Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setAttribute()

Tags: laravel

Estoy haciendo un store a mi base de datos de esta manera:

```
 public function store(DocumentoAutorFormRequest $request)
{
// Se crea un objeto vinculo
$vinculo = new DocumentoAutor;
//EL ORDEN ES EL MAXIMO ORDEN +1
$orden=DB::table('cntrl_autor')->max('orden');
$vinculo->orden = $orden+1;
$vinculo->extra=" ";
//Se crea la relacion
$vinculo->fk_doc = $request->get('fk_doc');
$vinculo->fk_autor = $request->get('fk_autor');
//cuando se inserta, va regresar a esta misma ruta
$ruta = "/cntrl_autor/ligar/".$request->get('id_documento');
//Extra no se como se maneja, pero se coloca como espacio vacio mientras
    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Vinculación Exitosa!');
    $vinculo->save();
    return Redirect::to($ruta);
}
```

y me tira el siguiente error:

```
Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setAttribute(). .. and exactly 2 expected
```

Mi request está así

```
class DocumentoAutor extends Model
{
protected $table='cntrl_autor';

protected $primaryKey=null;
public $timestamps=false;


protected $fillable =[
    'orden',
    'fk_doc',
    'fk_autor',
    'extra'
]; 

protected $guarded =[

];
```

el error me sale, sin embargo la inserción la esta haciendo bien en la base de datos me gustaría saber que estoy haciendo mal o porque sale ese error.

Comment: Hola Ccin, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla :D

Comment: ¿Cuál es la estructura de su tabla en la base de datos?

Comment: es una tabla así: orden (pk) fk_doc, fk_autor son llaves foraneas y extra que es varchar